# Maintaining libraries on a live site without Composer

Tags: 8, composer

I notice this question has been asked several times on here - and each time the answers always seem to involve using Composer one way or another! :-)

I get that one can get around shared hosting constraints by using Composer in their local dev environment and then uploading the lot, but what about maintaining libraries without Composer at all. Is it even possible?

I recall in D7 it was possible to manually download and maintain libraries in a nominated folder location. Is this still possible in D8?

Comment: Yes you'd just need to manually download all the required packages into the relevant places. Hopefully the readme.txt will have these instructions

Comment: Thanks Leigh - great to get a clear response on this as there seems to be so much confusion out there. Testing this now with the webform libraries. Seems to be working fine! Many thanks again.

Comment: It's been stated that Composer is not a requirement of Drupal 8, but I've never seen a tutorial explaining how to do it. Only comments from people who have tried to do it and found it a nightmare. See these comments: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/installing-drupal/2020-05-18/installing-drupal-8-with-or-without-composer#comment-13620817

Comment: Thanks Jaypan. Yes I've seen those dire warnings too. I suppose I'll just see how far I can get without using Composer and keep posting updates here and elsewhere on how that goes.
Right now its not going too badly as I have just managed to install all of the webform libraries in the /Libraries folder - old-school style, and have got Entity Print working with dompdf with no trouble at all. Let's see how we go...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out it is possible, at least in terms of getting modules like Webform and Entity Print working.  Both of these require libraries and many guides on installing them are emphatic that you MUST use composer for them to work.

I managed to get both of them working without using Composer:

Regular libraries such as those used by the Webform module can simply be extracted to the /Libraries folder. Simply create the directories specified in the admin/reports/status report after you instal the Webform module and put each library there.

Here is a great guide on manually installing dompdf (to use with modules like Entity Print) in the /Vendors directory: https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_print/issues/3081358#comment-13667896.

So far, at least, not so hard after all...

Comment: But how do you keep the libraries folder up to date?